# Access phone table data in the organization view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model called organization and another one called Phone,the organization id is found in the phone Model my question is how to access the phone table data in the view of the organization?

organization Model:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Password { get; set; }


    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }


    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public byte roleId  { get; set; }
```

Phone Model:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }

    //organization Model 
    public Organization organization { get; set; }
    public int organizationId { get; set; }
```

I want to access the phone in the registration page of the organization to be saved in the database in the phone table

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel which will connect both of the classes together, but without sample code it's hard to explain, something like:

(Those are the sample models)

```
public class Phone {
    public int Id { get;set; }
}

public class Organization {
    public int Id { get; set;;
}
```

Connection between the two:

```
public class OrganizationPhoneViewModel {
    public Phone Phone { get;set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

On the view you change the model to the OrganizationPhoneViewModel, and also on the HttpGet method you need to load the needed data, that's all :) But the best solution is to use the DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) instead of real (proxified) POCO objects from DB.

Comment: please can you see my edits to understand what i want and thanks i advance